# Simple decision tree (nested if-statement) in Python?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, decision-tree

I'd like to define a nested `if`-statement in JSON and test it with Python. I'm thinking about a simple **decision tree** with nested branches, being tested recursively.

**Pseudocode**:

```
# is_valid = (a == b OR a == a) AND c == c  # True
tree = {
    branches: [
        {
            value1: 'a',
            operator: '==',
            value2: 'b',
            child_connector: 'or'
            children: [
                {
                    value1: 'a',
                    operator: '==',
                    value2: 'a'
                }   
            ]
        },
        {
            connector: 'and',
            value1: 'c',
            operator: '==',
            value2: 'c'
        }
    ]
}

def is_tree_valid(tree):
    # TODO
    return

is_valid = is_tree_valid(tree)
```

When I googled for decision trees, I found a lot AI related, but often too deep. I'm looking for something simple and guess it's a common topic and was re-invented often enough.

I'd appreciate code snippets, modules or any other advice to complete `is_tree_valid()`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't the logic that should be inside `is_tree_valid()` depend on your definition of "valid"? I'm not totally clear on what you're trying to accomplish but check out the built-in [`ast` module](https://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#module-ast). You may be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: When prototyping, I would create a mapping of `key_name: validation_func` and use that. It's sort of bodgy, but works for smaller problems. But your dict looks like you're reinventing an LR parser. Take a look at [PLY](https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) package. You'd have to learn some lex and yacc, but if you're creating some sort of statement language/grammar, doing it the right way from the start will benefit you greatly later. `ast` is an option, but IIRC it works for Python syntax only.

Comment: @Chris the idea is to have some logic stored in a DB, as a json-string. This logic needs to be tested (true/false). The definition of valid is quiet simple as it can be directly translated to Python `if`-statements. I hope that answers your question. :)  Thanks for the link!

Comment: @BłażejMichalik Thank you very much for the link and keywords. The tree will be more complex, it's just a very simplified example.

Comment: What do `a`/`b`/`c` represent?  Are those just literals (which would be trivial), or are they some sort of values known to your (Python) evaluator?

Comment: @DavisHerring they're simple placeholders in the example. Each one can be understood as a variable containing the result of a function. Results are always booleans, integers or strings. The heavy stuff happens in the functions, the comparison afterwards is trivial (`IF (20 == 21 OR 'a' != 'b') AND True == False`). The challenge is the nesting.

Comment: @Mr.B.: Sure, but the most complicated part of the code is calling whatever those functions are (or identifying the results already obtained thence).

Comment: @DavisHerring Exactly. The branches already contain the pre-calculated results of `value1` and `value2`. It's "just" a recursive loop "building" a trivial `if`-statement.

Comment: @Mr.B.: So whatever is writing the JSON already knows all the *values* (not just expressions for them) and yet it chooses to encode the complicated set of comparisons and operators rather than just writing a boolean value?

Comment: @DavisHerring Exactly. Values are pre-calculated and stored in a cache. `a` will be replaced by the cached value (string, boolean, integer). You can imagine it as several monitoring logic-trees, comparing cached values.

Comment: @Mr.B.: Um, OK.  Can you pick a less strange encoding for the AST?  Your example shows both lists with `connector` relating to siblings and objects with `child_connector` relating to `children`.

Comment: @DavisHerring I could re-structure the tree. Can you recommend a pattern? The `connector` is `and` or `or` and `children` mean that the parent has to wrap the lower levels with `()`. I'm probably using wrong names here. My goal is *actually* quiet simple: structuring an `if`-statement as a string, parsing and testing it in Python.

Comment: @Mr.B.: Just have an object for each operator with three attributes: operator, left, and right.  If the operator is a comparison, the children are just strings/numbers; if it is a logical operation, they are more objects of the same type.

Comment: @DavisHerring Could you please clarify your advice a bit more? I don't fully get it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as much about the input as the algorithm, but designing them together is only reasonable.  The simplest encoding of the expression to evaluate is a direct translation of the [AST](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree):

```
{
  "operator": "and",
  "left": {
    "operator": "or",
    "left": {
      "operator": "==",
      "left": "a",
      "right": "b"
    },
    "right": {
      "operator": "==",
      "left": "a",
      "right": "a"
    }
  },
  "right": {
    "operator": "==",
    "left": "c",
    "right": "c"
  }
}
```

Then (after parsing into the obvious Python structure), evaluation looks like

```py
def evaluate(node):
  try: op=node['operator']
  except TypeError: return node  # leaf
  l=evaluate(node['left'])
  r=node['right']  # not evaluated yet
  if op=='==': return l==evaluate(r)
  elif op=='and': return l and evaluate(r)
  elif op=='or': return l or evaluate(r)
  else: raise ValueError("unknown operator: %r"%op)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this snippet. I don't see any brackets, which means the hierarchy will stay flat, correct? How can it handle, for example, `(a == b OR a == a) AND c == c`?

Comment: @Mr.B.: The JSON is nested exactly as deeply as the expression; parentheses (where they would not be implied by precedence) are implied by the object hierarchy.  In this case, the *or* is the left operand of the *and*.

Comment: Ah, of course, it's nested. :-) I'm looking forward to test it tomorrow with a fresh brain. Thank you very much again.